# Java- How to print blank for null date using java printf

Tags: java

I am using `PrintWriter.printf()` function to write to a file in java using the following format:

`%1$s,%2$s,%3$s,%4$s,%5$tF,%n`

This gives me an output like this:

```
25563,XY63563,Greame,Thomas,1942-04-07,

341411,YY2524522,Thayer,Michael,1945-03-19,

472452,TR254252,Brook,null,null,
```

Is there a way to customize `printf` to get blanks for null values.

I can do a null check for string values and replace null with blanks. How do I handle null date values in `printf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to do this in two steps:

```
String formattedDate = (date == null) ? "" : String.format("%tF", date);
```

then use `printf` again with a format string like

```
"%1$s,%2$s,%3$s,%4$s,%5$s,%n"
```

and `formattedDate` as the fifth argument (which is now formatted with `%s`).  I don't see a way to get a format string to handle null values in a custom way.

Comment: So there is no way to customize null handling by printf function. Doing individual null checks is too verbose. I want to use printf to handle multiple data types in one statement. Handling null values outside printf requires to convert every data value to string type and then print.

Comment: @pawindergupta I think that's right, that `printf` and `String.format` don't give you a way to do it.  But doing something like `printf("%1$s,%2$s,%3$s,%4$s,%5$s,%n",fmt(a),fmt(b),fmt(c)...)` doesn't seem too onerous to me, where you'd write an overloaded `fmt` method for different types that does whatever special thing you want for null.  Or if you were really clever, you could write a wrapper for `printf` that checks its `Object` arguments for null, does something special with them, and uses `printf` to handle the rest.  But that would require parsing the format string yourself.